# Define specific output count in EXPR command

Tags: unix

I have a scenario wherein I want to have 9 character count in expr.

I have sample code which is:

```
    var1=012345678 #this is 9 characters
    sum=`expr $var1 + 1`
    echo "$sum"
```

Here is the result:

```
    ./sample.sh : 12345679 #this is only 8 characters
```

My expected output:

```
    ./sample.sh : 012345679
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The leading zero is removed when doing the math.
You can force a 9 length output using `printf "%09d" 123`.
When you try to use the the syntax `((sum=${var1} + 1 ))` you have another problem: When the first digit is `0`, bash expects a different radix.
You can remove the first `0` with

```
var1=012345678
echo "${var1#0}"
```

This only helps with your input, not with `00012`. 
Removing the leading zeroes and printing the sum can be done with `echo $((10#$var1))`

```
var1=00012345678
((sum=$((10#$var1)) + 1))
printf "%09d\n" $sum
```

This can be solved easier with

```
var1=00012345678
echo "${var1} 1" |awk '{ printf("%09d\n", $1 + $2) }'
```

You can avoid the `echo` with

```
awk -v var1=$var1 'BEGIN { printf("%09d\n", var1 + 1) }'
```

The `BEGIN` is used for parsing without an inputfile.
The option `-v` is a clean way to use a shell variable inside an awk script.
Do not try things with quotes, one day it will shoot your own foot:

```
# Don't do this
awk 'BEGIN { printf("%09d\n", '${var1}' + 1) }' # Just do not do it
```

Comment: Could you please explain the part "%09d", what it means when used in awk?

Comment: `%d`=parameter is integer. `09` = minimal length 9 filled with leading zeroes if needed for length. Search for `printf format` for more information.